# Dart: default gitignore?

Tags: dart

I created a new app and the Dart Editor (M4) created a slew of files and folders. Now I'm not sure which I can safely put in the gitignore. Here's the tree:

```
app/.buildlog
app/build.dart
app/packages/analyzer_experimental
app/packages/args
app/packages/browser
app/packages/csslib
app/packages/html5lib
app/packages/js
app/packages/logging
app/packages/meta
app/packages/pathos
app/packages/source_maps
app/packages/unittest
app/packages/web_ui
app/pubspec.lock
app/pubspec.yaml
app/web/app.css
app/web/app.dart
app/web/app.html
app/web/out/app.css
app/web/out/app.dart
app/web/out/app.dart.map
app/web/out/app.html
app/web/out/app.html_bootstrap.dart
app/web/out/packages
app/web/out/xclickcounter.dart
app/web/out/xclickcounter.dart.map
app/web/packages
app/web/xclickcounter.dart
app/web/xclickcounter.html
```

I assume the following files can be ignored:

```
app/.buildlog
app/packages/*
app/web/out/*
app/web/packages
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Here is Ladicek .gitignore:  https://github.com/Ladicek/modern-web-demos/blob/master/.gitignore

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [*What Not to Commit* on dartlang.org](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/private-files.html):

```
# files and directories created by pub
.dart_tool/
.packages
.pub/
build/
pubspec.lock  # Except for application packages
# API documentation directory created by dartdoc
doc/api/
# files and directories created by other development environments
*.iml         # IntelliJ
*.ipr         # IntelliJ
*.iws         # IntelliJ
.idea/        # IntelliJ
.DS_Store     # Mac
# generated JavaScript files
*.dart.js
*.info.json      # Produced by the --dump-info flag.
*.js             # When generated by dart2js. Don't specify *.js if your
                 # project includes source files written in JavaScript.
*.js_
*.js.deps
*.js.map
```

Answer (score 5):

**Don’t commit** the following files and directories created by pub, Dart Editor, and dart2js:

```
packages/
pubspec.lock  // Except for application packages
.project
.buildlog
*.js_
*.js.deps
*.js.map
```

**Don’t commit** files and directories dropped by other development environments. For example:

```
.project      // Eclipse
*.iml         // IntelliJ
*.ipr         // IntelliJ
*.iws         // IntelliJ
.idea/        // IntelliJ
.DS_Store     // Mac
```

**Avoid committing** generated JavaScript files:

```
*.dart.js
```

For more details, read https://www.dartlang.org/tools/private-files.html.

Answer (score 2):

**Dart default**

```gitignore
.packages      # mapping file from package names to local path
packages       # until `--no-package-symlinks` is the default
build/         # contains the output of `pub build`
.pubspec.lock  # controversial - Dart guideline is to only commit
               #     for applications but not for packages
.pub/          # cache files generated by `pub` 
               # .pub was moved to .dart_tool/.pub
```

**build** The new https://github.com/dart-lang/build package introduces a

```gitignore
.dart_tool/
```

directory which should be excluded.

> When it comes to generated files it is generally best to not submit them to source control, but a specific Builder may provide a recommendation otherwise.

**IDE**

```gitignore
.idea # IntelliJ, WebStorm
```

**bazel**

```gitignore
/bazel-*
.bazelify
packages.bzl
BUILD
WORKSPACE
```

See also

- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Dart.gitignore
- https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/private-files

Answer (score 1):

An up to date sample Dart .gitignore is available in the gitignore repo on Github:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Dart.gitignore

Note that this does not contain IDE or editor files, just Dart files. You can find IDE and editor .gitignores in the same repo.

I include `doc/api` in my .gitignore. I tend to write substantial documentation comments and I like to use `dartdoc` to generate the documentation for review.